# Yii - how to read excel file sheets using yexcel plugin

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using Yexcel - YII plugin that is a wrapper for PHPEXcel for a web application that need to read and parse different excel files.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yexcel/

I am able to read and use the data in excel files that are single means they have only 
one sheet but when it comes to reading other sheets in same excel file then i cannot read those because it gives me error.Using PHPExcel we can set active sheets and read
 like this

`$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // first sheet`

but how can we do this using YII's yexcel plugin?

Because when i call this function with yexcel object it gives me error

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Yexcel::setActiveSheetIndex()
```

Issue: How to access all sheets in an Excel file.

Any help, guidance in right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the import csv  extension

[yii import csv](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/importcsv/)

Answer (score 1):

You can either extend Yexcel class and write your own method based on Yexcel->readActiveSheet() or hardcode it (bad practice).

Below is my modified version:

```
        public function readActiveSheet( $file, $activeSheet = 0 )
        {
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($activeSheet);
            $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

            return $sheetData;
        }
```

You can use it as following:

```
$sheet_attay = Yii::app()->yexcel->readActiveSheet($filename, 1);
```